# javaFx Animation ScaleTransition

Tags: animation, javafx, scenebuilder

My problem is that when I scale an `anchorPane` with radius `15px` with `scaleTransition` and increase its width the looks is just stretched. Otherwise when I just use `setPrefWidth()` it stays the same but there is no animation with `setPrefWidth()`. I just want the `anchorPane` to get wider with the same radius. How can I do it?

Thats the code that makes the `anchorPane` radius stretched.

```
ScaleTransition second = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(2), main);
second.setToX(2);
second.play();`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just animate the `prefWidthProperty()`. Assuming you create the animation after the anchor pane `main` has been laid out, you can do:

```
Timeline second = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(main.prefWidthProperty(), main.getWidth())),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(main.prefWidthProperty(), 2 * main.getWidth())))
);
second.play();
```

Comment: first thing i realy realy thank you man for that fast reply ...    second its actually works .... i stayed all the morning thinking about how can i do it then i post here my question for last try ....  you helped me man so much realy thank you ... much love <3

Comment: another question man >>> the code u send it helped me so make wider but to right side ... how can i make it to the left side .. i have tried (-300) but not work its just like it move until 0 value of PrefWidth then its unvisable

Comment: @abdlmjeedal-king Translate it while you scale it.

Comment: didnt get you ... can you give me an example ?

Comment: i mean i can make it wider only using timeline ... but when i want to move it to left side its just Disappear ...